# Changing running footer in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, header-footer

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title[Peeling Bananas]{How to Peel a Banana?}
\date[January 5, 2016]{Fruit Seminar \\ January 5, 2016}
\author[John C. Doe and Jane E. Poe]{John C. Doe and Jane E. Poe}
\institute{Harvard University}

\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}

\end{document}
```

The first part of the "running footer" reads "John C. Doe and Jane E. Poe (Harvard University)", and there's not enough space for it. So I want to remove the "(Harvard University)" part. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\institute[]{Harvard University}` or even `\institute[Harvard]{Harvard University}`, instead of your command `\institute{Harvard University}`.

It's strange that the above suggestion displays correctly for me, but not for the OP.

Updated answer: from a def in the file `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty` I've deleted `(\insertshortinstitute)` from  the command that inserts the institute name or short name.

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
   \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
```

I hope this works.

Comment: The first option renders "John C. Doe and Jane E. Poe ()", which is even worse because of the empty parentheses. I would like to remove the parentheses altogether.

Comment: @nan on my TeX system, the parentheses were not visible. I'll search for a solution, but I'm sure someone else will know a correct method.

Comment: My sty file indeed does not contain the `ifempty` part. Thanks!